# Macro to filter and copy data in new tab

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to filter the data (have 5-6 filter) and copy the data into the new sheet in the same workbook . 
Here is the example [there are multiple columns , the data which i need in to new tab is 
Virtual - NO
Server - NO
LCM Status- 0 and 1
Status - Active and Quarantine 
Most frequent User - Only name with test in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfza4.png)

Thank you so much in Advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: So what is your question? (Post your code, state where it goes wrong, and we will be happy to help! Surely you don't expect us to do your job for you.)

Comment: Thank you so much Vacip, i am not familiar to vba and code...i have tried certain code that is available on google but i am not able to develop it ...i would really appreciate if you could please help me thank you peace

Comment: My question is i need filtered data into new sheet . what i usually do is put the filter on 5 columns 
1)Virtual - NO (2)Server - NO (3)LCM Status- 0 and 1 (4)Status - Active and Quarantine (5)Most frequent User - Only name with test in it and then put the filterd data into new sheet and now i want to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

From your Excel Workbook, go to the page with your data to be filtered.  Click on the "Developer" tab.  If you do not see a developer tab on the ribbon, check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9be

On the left side of the developer ribbon you will see a link for "Record Macro."  Click that link.  Every action you take now will be automatically recorded to a macro.

Sort the data on your sheet exactly the way you need it sorted.  Create a new sheet on the bottom by clicking on the new sheet "+" plus sign.  Return to your data sheet.  Select the data you want to copy to the new sheet.  Copy by Cntrl-C.  Go to your new sheet and select the cell you want the data to start copying to.  Paste the copied data with Cntrl-V.

Go to the developer tab and hit "Stop Recording."  Go to the VBA editor by simultaneously clicking ALT-F11.  On the left side click "Modules".  There should be a module with your recorded macro in it.

The macro will do everything you asked us to do.  You can use it as often as you like.  to use it again simply go to the Developer Tab and click "Macros."  A list of macros will pop up, including the one you just made.  Clicking on it will make it perform the same actions again.  You can change the name of the macro to anything you like.  You musat start the name with a letter and it can have no blank spaces.

The automatic macro is your friend if you are trying to learn VBA.  It will help you learn the very basics.  Once you get the basics down you can then get a little fancier with VBA, which is the best language I've come across.  For now, though, what you asked to do is a very simple procedure that can be handled with the macro recorder.